# Servlet build failed : module has not been deployed

Tags: java, servlets

I am using glassfish 4.1.1 with derby database. I am using java version 15. Image to the error is shown below :[the module has not been deployed.  see the server log for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhsNP.jpg)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community. We would love to help, but it's a little unclear what you need. Please provide some information on: what you are trying to do/accomplish, what the problem is that you are having, and what you have tried already to resolve it. Also please copy the error message into your answer, instead of linking an image. Doing these things will make it easier to get help and a better experience overall. [see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Netbeans 8.2 with Java8 and Glassfish server 4.1.1 to resolve this issue.
glassfish 4.1.1 is inbuilt on netbeans 8.2 and Glassfish 4.1.1 is not compatible with JDK15... I had the same error.. this worked for me..

Comment: Why? What difference does that make?

Comment: glassfish 4.1.1 is inbuilt on netbeans 8.2 and Glassfish 4.1.1 is not compatible with JDK15... I had the same error.. this worked for me.. so I suggested it

Comment: You should edit your answer to include that detail!

Comment: My bad.. I'm still new to all this